# c++ class constructor for array

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I am writing a `Matrix2D` class. At the beginning I was using constructor as folows,

**My code:**

```
Matrix2D(float a,float b, float c,float d)
{
    a_=a;
    ....
}
```

However, I have just realized that it would be a lot better if I could use multi dimensional `array [2][2]`. That's where the problem lies, 
How do I write constructor for array ?

```
class Matrix
{
    float matrix[2][2];
    public:
    Matrix2D(float a,float b,float c, float d)
    {
        matrix[2][2]={a,b,c,d} // not valid
    }
}
```

Just to let you know, I don't ask for a complete code. 
I just need someone to put me on a right track.

Comment: BTW, the class name and constructor name need to match.

Comment: thx, its just typo, they match in a source code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For **C++11** you can do:

```
Matrix(float a,float b,float c, float d) :
   matrix{{a,b},{c,d}}
{
}
```

There's no clean alternative for **C++03**.

Comment: You need to take off the parentheses, i.e. `matrix{{a,b},{c,d}}` because it's an array.

Comment: [LWS](http://liveworkspace.org/code/78ee95b0bc9e758d429428167b436fca) uses gcc 4.7.2

Comment: ok, I have tried it and apparently vs 2010 doesnt support this feature,  so I will have to go with " matrix[0][0]=a; " and so on.. Thx for support

Answer (score 2):

```
matrix[0][0] = a; // initialize one element
```

and so on.

Comment: Thx for the answer. That's the way I'll do it

Answer (score 1):

matrix[0][0] = value you want to matrix [n][n] = value you want but count up in a loop
so the matrix can be dynamic in size or you can reuse your code later.

```
for(int ii(0); ii < first dimension size; ++ii)
{
   for(int ll(0); ii < second dimension size; ++ll)
   {
     matrix[ii][ll] = value you want;
   }
}
```

this will make your code more extensible and more useful outside of this application and maybe it's not useful or maybe it is.

Answer (score 0):

If it will be a matrix 2X2, then you can pass a float array and then loop through it.

for example

```
for(int x = 0;x<4;x++)
{
    matrix[0][x] = myarray[x];
}
```

Comment: @LuchianGrigore how is that invalid?

Comment: @coolbartek If `matrix` is declared as `float matrix[2][2]` then `matrix[0][3]` is obviously invalid.

Comment: it looks fine for me, an two-dimensional array is actually a normal array, where you can access the elements by [0][x]. An array[x][y] is the same as an array[0][x*y]

Comment: @coolbartek: Don't you mean that `array[y][x]` is the same as `array[0][x+y*width]`?

Comment: @Luchian, are you forgetting that `a[i]` is the same as `*(a + i)` for built-in types?

Comment: @BenVoigt I am. :( pretty late here.

Comment: @BenVoigt yes, that is what i meant

Answer (score 0):

Luchian's version is best if you have a C++11 compiler.  Here's one that works for all versions of C++:

```
struct matrix_holder { float matrix[2][2]; };

class Matrix : matrix_holder
{
    static matrix_holder pack(float a,float b,float c, float d)
    {
        matrix_holder h = { {{a, b}, {c, d}} };
        return h;
    }

public:
    Matrix(float a,float b,float c, float d) : matrix_holder(pack(a,b,c,d))
    {
    }
};
```

The optimizer will inline away the helper.